# How to count everything but letters at end of a string

Tags: c#, string

I have a random string and need to know the number of *non-letter / non-number* characters *at the end* of it.

For example:

`"Some text."` should result in **1**

`"More text 123 !.?"` should result in **4** (blanks included)

`"Even more text 123"` should result in **0**

How can I do that?

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself?

Comment: @RandomCoder I didn't get the idea of how to do it, so I couldn't really try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with using Linq is that `Enumerable.Reverse()` makes a copy of the string as a char array and iterates backwards through it, which is not efficient. That might not matter at all to you, but a much more efficient approach is to just loop backwards over the string's characters like so:

```
string test = "the string to test !*&*& ";

int i;

for (i = test.Length - 1; i >= 0 && !char.IsLetterOrDigit(test[i]); --i)
    ;

int n = test.Length - i - 1; // n is the count of non-letter/non-digit chars
```

If you wanted it as a method to call:

```
public static int CountNonLetterDigitCharsAtEnd(string input)
{
    int i;

    for (i = input.Length - 1; i >= 0 && !char.IsLetterOrDigit(input[i]); --i)
        ;

    return input.Length - i - 1;
}
```

Comment: Chose this solution as correct answer because I don't need to use Linq. Thanks

Answer (score 6):

You can try *Linq*:

```
  string source = "More text 123 !.?";

  int result = source
    .Reverse()
    .TakeWhile(c => !char.IsLetterOrDigit(c))
    .Count();
```

**Demo:**

```
string[] tests = new string[] {
  "Some text.",
  "More text 123 !.?",
  "Even more text 123"
};

string demo = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, tests
  .Select(s => $"{s,-30} : {s.Reverse().TakeWhile(c => !char.IsLetterOrDigit(c)).Count()}"));

Console.Write(demo);
```

**Outcome:**

```
Some text.                     : 1
More text 123 !.?              : 4
Even more text 123             : 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate backwards through the string and use [Char.IsLetterOrDigit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.char.isletterordigit?view=netframework-4.8) to determine if it's non-alphanumeric. When you find a letter or digit then stop and return the count.

Answer (score 0):

It's easy with LINQ:

```
using System.Linq;
```

This function also handles null strings and returns -1 for them.

```
    public static int CountNonLettersAtEnd(string input)
        => input?.Reverse().TakeWhile(c => !char.IsLetterOrDigit(c)).Count() ?? -1;
```